# SQL INSERT INTO using subquery without value

Tags: sql, mysql, insert, subquery

When using the SQL INSERT INTO with subquery, I need to use `SELECT` after the `INSERT INTO`, but not `VALUE`.

When I write the following code

```
INSERT INTO orders_archived
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE order_date < "2018-01-01"
```

there is no `VALUE` any more.

Why does this logic work?

Comment: That is an alternative `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax that most DB's have, and is in [their documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html). It works because the `orders_archived` has the _same number of columns_ as `orders` so column/value pairs are the same between the tables, so no need to explicitly name the column/value pairs. The same is very useful migrating data from other sources (say like company mergers) where column names differ, but aliasing the columns with `AS` in the `SELECT` to match can help migrate/import the data from other systems into another.

Comment: `INSERT .. SELECT` is base syntax whereas `INSERT .. VALUES` is syntactic sugar. `INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, 2);` is really `INSERT INTO table SELECT 1, 2;`.

Comment: "there is no `VALUE` any more" is not clear. When was there a VALUE? Why do you think there has to be a VALUE? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Reference competent documentation. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

When you have same number of column in your `orders_archived` and `orders` table, the insert statement works with the select.

However, if both the table structure are different, you cannot insert the data from a different table. You should design a customized select statement to insert into the table to have same number of columns.

Both the above solutions are used only if you are trying to insert from another table. If you are inserting the values of your own, you should have `values` key word followed by your attributes.